# Big-O of containsValue for Guava HashBiMap

Tags: java, guava, bimap

I am interested in using a Map that will contain unique keys and values. I also would like to have O(1) complexity for `.containsKey()` and `.containsValue()`. To me, it seems like a `HashBiMap` should be able to support this complexity because of the uniqueness of both the keys and values in the map and hashing. Is this a correct assumption?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A ***PROPERLY IMPLEMENTED*** two-way `HashMap` (In this case, a `HashBiMap`) indeed has a runtime complexity of O(1) for `containsKey` and `containsValue`.

Comment: Very true! Looking at the source code for the `HashBiMap` seems to confirm the O(1) complexity for both methods. https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.java

Comment: Okay then.. well glad we could close that book.